# Java applet using Dreamweaver

Tags: java, iframe, applet, dreamweaver

**I am having a problem putting a java applet on a website using Dreamweaver CS5.**

This is the page where I am having the problem:
http://www.typingsquad.com/employment.html

This is a picture of what I see in dreamweaver:
http://i895.photobucket.com/albums/ac157/daltonward1/javaAppletProblem.png

Based on what I have read on the internet, I have tried the three following methods, but only one has worked.

**First**, I tried putting the applet on the webpage by using media-applet. The picture posted shows how I tried to implement that. However, as you can see on the website when viewing the first box, it states that there is an error.

*"java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file Calculator/html"*

I've done some reading on this error, but I cannot find a solution.

The **second** thing I tried is using an IFrame using the direct link of the html file on the server. As you can see, all that appears is a blank box.

The **third** thing I tried using was a hyperlink, which actually did work. No errors, but its not the effect I was going for.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my use of Iframe and/or applet on dreamweaver? 
Could it be that my files aren't grouped together right on the server?

I'm really into writing Java applications and applets, but my friend just got into web development and has asked me to write some simple programs for him. Any help will be greatly appreciated and sorry if my questions could have been simply found else where as I am still new to computer programming as well.

Thanks,
James Ward

Comment: *"..my friend just got into web development and has asked me to write some simple programs for him."*  If they can be done in JS, that would be the better option.

Comment: If your problem has been resolved, you should mark an answer as accepted rather than putting "<Resolved>" in the question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file Calculator/html
```

This means the JRE is asking for a class but getting an HTML page (probably stating '404, resource/page not found') that starts with `<htm`.  More details on [the answer](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9814811#9814811) at the OTN.

---

Now I look at the source and see:

```
<applet code="Calculator.html" codebase = "Java Applets/Calculator/bin" width="500" height="300">
</applet>
```

I realize it is because the page is specifying an HTML instead of a class in the `code` attribute.  These things do not work by magic, you need to have *some* idea of what you're doing if you hope to deploy an applet successfully.

---

If http://www.typingsquad.com/Calculator.html works as you expect, the fix will be to change the `applet` element in the original page to..

```
<applet code="Calculator.class" width="500" height="300">
</applet>
```

I am guessing the `codebase` listed in the original HTML is an artifact of your development environment.  If not, you will need to add that, but if that is the case, I would ***strongly*** recommend using only directories names with:

1. All lower case letters.
2. No spaces.

Answer (score 0):

i saw the html from the site.. you are saying

```
  <applet code="Calculator.html" codebase = "Java Applets/Calculator/bin" width="500" height="300">
  </applet>
```

you should be saying

```
code="Calculator.class"
```

the issue is that the system is getting a HTML document which is not parsable as a java class file.. just change the applet tag and things will work properly.

I'd recommend you creating a jar file and using the JAR as the codebase.. its simpler and better than having a class file